# Does Reduce have problems with greek symbols that lead to wrong results?

Tags: equation-solving, symbols

I call `Reduce` on the following simple system of inequalities

```
e = ((-4 + Sqrt[(-2 + λ)^2] + 3 λ) Log[p] + 4 λ Log[β])/(2 λ);
Reduce[e > 0 && 1 > λ > 0 && 1 > p > 0 && 1 > β > 0, λ, Reals]
```

Mathematica returns `False`, which is wrong and can be seen from

```
e /. {λ -> 1/2, p -> 0.1, β -> 0.9}
```

which returns `2.09186`.

However a simple change of symbols

```
f = ((-4 + Sqrt[(-2 + l)^2] + 3 l) Log[p] + 4 l Log[b])/(2 l);
Reduce[f > 0 && 1 > l > 0 && 1 > p > 0 && 1 > b > 0, l, Reals]
```

yields the desired result

```
0 < b < 1 && 0 < p < 1 && 0 < l < Log[p]/(2 Log[b] + Log[p])
```

Also note that that the system with greek letters but without constraints on `β` also yields correct results

```
Reduce[e > 0 && 1 > λ > 0 && 1 > p > 0, λ, Reals]
```

returns

```
0 < p < 1 && ((Log[β] <= 0 && 0 < λ < Log[p]/(Log[p] + 2 Log[β])) || (Log[β] > 0 &&  0 < λ < 1))
```

Can anybody explain this behavior?

(I have replicated this behavior in a separate notebook on a freshly started kernel session)

Comment: Very strange indeed. It is not caused by Greek letters. When you replace only the character beta with b, you get a correct result, but when you replace it with z, the result is False again.

Comment: This has come up before, but I cannot find it. Mathematica rearranges `Orderless` expressions according to the standard ordering of their terms (in this case the Log[b] term appears in different positions in `e` and `f`). The transformations attempted by `Reduce` depend on the expression structure and in some cases one form cannot be solved while the other can.

Comment: @Simon. Yes, I vaguely remember having seen something like this before, but that must have been many, many years ago in good old mathgroup. When I remember it right, it has something to do with the computation of Groebner bases, and I think it was Andrzej Kozlowsky explaining it. I am not sure if it applies here.

Comment: I understand that the implicit ordering done by Mathematica can affect the results of `Reduce` and its ability to provide a useful transformation. But if it is just that why does it come up with a wrong result rather than an untransformed expression or similar.  Would you consider this a bug?